# Change color button WooCommerce product page

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product

I'm having a problem with WooCommerce. I'm developing a website with Divi and WooCommerce. The buttons on the website have a specific style and I want that in the page products the buttons have the same style but I can't do it.

I installed the WooCommerce Color plugin but it doesn't work.

I have a child theme and on the developer console I looked for the specific class of this button and I found this class: ".single_add_to_cart_button button alt"

So in the CSS of the child theme I added:

```
.single_add_to_cart_button button alt { 
    color: #00000 !important;
}
```

But it doesn't work either.

This is the website: http://centromindfulnessmadrid.com/ and I want to change the buttons on these pages: http://centromindfulnessmadrid.com/producto/mindfulness-retiro-de-1-dia-sabado-24/ The button: "Añadir al carrito".

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate this is an old post, and it looks like you have resolved it, but the alt class would require a period as it is not an HTML element.

You will also have an inheritance issue as WooCommerce is very strict.

This would be closer to what you need, but you can probably narrow down the classes to one or two:

```
.woocommerce .single_add_to_cart_button button .alt { 
  color: #00000;
}
```